# sksprite - node moving opposite direction

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, core-motion

I've a spaceship, which I'm trying to move left or right based on device tilting. The code is working fine when I sit and play. Spaceship moves to right when I tilt iPhone to right and moves to left when I tilt to left.

**Issue** - However, when I lie flat down and tilt device, the spaceship moves in opposite direction.

**Expectation** - I want the spaceship to move always in the direction of tilt, irrespective of how I hold the iPhone.

Below is the code.

**Setting up Core Motion**

```
func setupCoreMotion() {
    motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.2
    let queue = OperationQueue()

    motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: queue, withHandler: {
        accelerometerData, error in
        guard let accelerometerData = accelerometerData else {
            return
        }
        let acceleration = accelerometerData.acceleration
        self.xAcceleration = (CGFloat(acceleration.y) * 1.75) + (self.xAcceleration * 0.25)
    })
}
```

**Moving spaceship**

```
func moveSpaceship() {

    if spaceship.position.x < 1935.00 && spaceship.position.x > 120.0 {
        spaceship.physicsBody!.velocity.dx = xAcceleration * 3000.0

    } else { //This is to slow down spaceship towards the edges
        spaceship.physicsBody!.velocity.dx = xAcceleration * 1000.0
    }

    spaceshipPreviousPositionX.dx = spaceship.position.x
}
```

Comment: I do not think your math for xAccelerator works correctly If I am going 10, and I tilt right, it becomes (2.5 + 1.75) then (1.0625 + 1.75) then (.703125 + 1.75) Then if I tilt left I would get 0.61328125 - 1.75 then -0.2841796875 -1.75 ..... etc, The numbers look like going right decelerates, and going left accelerates, but in a weird way